# Why does my dynamic neural network have 0 parameters?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have defined the following neural network:

```
class Q_function(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size=3, hidden_size=5, num_layers=3, learning_rate=0.01):
        super(Q_function, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.layers = []
        for i in num_layers:
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)) 
            self.append(nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size,1))
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layers[0](x)
        for lay in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            out = self.layers[lay](out)
        return out
```

When I run:

```
net = Q_function()
list(net.parameters())
```

I get the output as an empty list `[]`. Can someone explain why the network has no parameters? How to register the parameters? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytorch tracks parameters through specific constructor classes. It has no visibility into arbitrary lists.

To track your list of modules, you need to wrap it in a [nn.Sequential](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html) or [nn.ModuleList](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html)

```py
class Q_function(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size=3, hidden_size=5, num_layers=3, learning_rate=0.01):
        super(Q_function, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.layers = []
        for i in num_layers:
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)) 
            self.append(nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size,1))
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(self.layers)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layers[0](x)
        for lay in range(1,len(self.layers)):
            out = self.layers[lay](out)
        return out
```

That said, there are also a number of errors in your model code. You probably want something like this:

```py
class Q_function(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size=3, hidden_size=5, num_layers=3, learning_rate=0.01):
        super(Q_function, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.layers = [nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size), nn.ReLU()]
        for i in range(num_layers-1):
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)) 
            self.layers.append(nn.ReLU())
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(hidden_size,1))
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(*self.layers)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layers(x)
        return x
```